# iPad UIPickerView causing problems

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uipickerview

Can someone show me how I can get a `UIPickerView` working on the iPad? I'm trying to have a `UIPickerView` in the middle of the screen. Here is the current code I have:

```
if(IDIOM == IPAD)
    namePickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 345, 400, 216)];
else
    namePickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 245, 0, 0)];

namePickerView.delegate = self;
namePickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
```

So this just puts the picker view on the far left. On the iPhone, everything is perfect. **But on the iPad, this doesn't work**. As soon as I try to scroll through the values, nothing movies. The UIPickerView does not respond to any touches. What is the issue here? I just want to put a UIPickerView of default size in the middle of my iPad screen, 345 pixels down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIPickerViews on the ipad don't have a default size (ie width).

change

```
namePickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 345, 0, 0)];
```

to

```
namePickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 345, 400, 216)];
```

Comment: But as soon as I change the X value, it has the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure the if statement is correct? Add some NSLog to see if it uses the correct branch.